# odoo iterate over all product

Tags: loops, odoo

I wanted to iterate over all products and calculate list_price from another field.
this is the code that I wrote:

```
class AedPriceCalculator(models.TransientModel):

_name = "aed.pricecalculator"

_inherit = ['product.template']

aed_current_price = fields.Monetary('current AED price in IRR', required=True, translate=True)
currency_id = fields.Many2one(
    'res.currency', 'Currency',default=lambda self: self.env['res.currency'].search([('name', '=', 'AED')]).id,readonly=True)



@api.multi
def price_calculate_ae(self):
        products = self.env['product.template'].search(['sale_ok', '=' ,True])
        for product in products:
            if product.amount_in_aed:
                product.list_price = self.aed_current_price * product.amount_in_aed
            else:
                pass
```

but when I call the related button.
this error will appear:

```
    The operation cannot be completed:
- Create/update: a mandatory field is not set.
- Delete: another model requires the record being deleted. If possible, archive it instead.

Model: aed.pricecalculator (aed.pricecalculator), Field: Name(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

`aed.pricecalculator` model inherit from `product.template` and the `name` field is required in product template (copied as-is).

When you click on the button and call `price_calculate_ae` method, Odoo will try to call the create method without providing a value for `name` field and that's why you see this error message.

You don't need to inherit `product.template` to iterate over all products and calculate list_price